# continuous line break when event occurs

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a new number to be displayed in a new line every time I click the button using javascript, however I'm at a loss of how to do this. my code:

```js
var x = 1;

function tri() {
  var u = x++;
  document.getElementById('d1').innerHTML = x + "<br/>" + u;

};
```

```html
<div class="new_div">
  <div class="div1">
    <button onclick="tri()">click me first</button>
    <article class="art1">
      <h3>Bible</h3>
      <br>
      <br>
      <h3>Info</h3>
      <p id="d1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in </p>
```

As you can see I am incrementing the value of x and I am trying to display that result as well as the previous value of x, therefore I would like my code to look like this when i click the button:

1
   2
   3
   4
   etc... with each number being in a new line.

and not:
    For the value (1) which becomes 2 when the button is clicked, and 3 when the button is clicked again. 
    ; and for the value (2) which becomes 3 when the button is clicked, and 4 when the button is clicked again...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation

Comment: Perhaps you want `document.getElementById('d1').innerHTML += x...` and make the button type="button" just in case you ever wrap in a form

Comment: Do you need to display the "Lorem ipsum" statement after you click the button?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var x = 1;
function tri() {
if(x==1)
{
document.getElementById('d1').innerHTML="";
}
document.getElementById('d1').innerHTML += x++ + "<br>";
};
```

Comment: It is a shortcut method. For eg, x+=5 means x=x+5

Comment: the problem was fixed, thank you, one more question, why didn't x increment automatically when the button was clicked, since the value of x was already one?

Comment: When you say, x=5, it means that the value at the right-hand side(ie 5) is assigned to the variable at the left-hand side(ie. x). When you use the statement x=2, the value 5 will be replaced by 2.

Answer (score -1):

Then try this if you want to get all previews results:-

```
function tri(){
    var result = "1";
    for(var i=2; i<=x; i++)
        result += "<br/>" + i.toString();
    document.getElementById('d1').innerHTML= result;
    x++;
};
```